# php ltrim breaks regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, trim

I have a bit of a puzzle for you, or maybe not.
Check this piece:

```
$query = ' SELECT account.account_no,
       account.accountname,
       accountbillads.bill_city,
       account.website,
       account.phone,
       CASE
         WHEN ( users.user_name NOT LIKE "" ) THEN users.user_name
         ELSE groups.groupname
       END AS user_name,
       entity.crmid,
       account.accountid,
       account.parentid,
       partner.partnerid      
FROM   account
       INNER JOIN entity
               ON entity.crmid = account.accountid
       INNER JOIN currency_info AS CurrencyInfoTable
               ON CurrencyInfoTable.id =
                  entity.record_currency_id
WHERE  entity.deleted = 0   ';

$query = ltrim($query);

preg_match("/^select ((.|\n)*?)\bfrom\b((.|\n)*?)\bselect\b/i", $query, $matches);

print('finito');
print_r($matches);
```

On my server this crashes and no error nowhere.

Surprisingly, the tricky line is        *$query = ltrim($query);*
Without this line, everything works fine.

There are a couple of more things to this:
The sensitive part of the regex is the last ungreedy search for 'select'. If there isn't a second select to be found, than crash. The length of the query matters. Also, note that in a phpunits run, on the same machine, this problem doesn't exist.

My gathering is that *ltrim* does something to the string but I'm not sure what.

Can someone explain this?

Edit. All right, it seems that ltrim is not the problem. If I just give the string without a starting blank I have a crash. It might be related to pcre.backtrack_limit and pcre.recursion_limit settings but I've tried that and it was no change.

Edit2. The crash is 'Connection interrupted' in the browser. No full server crash but the script execution halts. And again, no error in log.

Problem solved. I had to replace (.|\n) with /s at the end. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: "no error nowhere" = an error somewhere?

Comment: You should escape the backslashes inside your regular expression (`\b` -> `\\b`).

Comment: what ltrim is do here is removing the leading space from the query if any.

Comment: [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) removes leading whitespace, nothing else.

Comment: What exactly is this regex suppose to match? Your query only contains one `select`. Also, you can save yourself the `(.|\n)` verbosity by using the `/s` switch. For example: `/^select (.*)\bfrom\b(.*)/si`

Comment: That's exactly what I want. If I have a second 'select' after the first 'from' than I want a match. if not, no match. Am I doing wrong? Thanks for the /s suggestion.

Comment: I don't think so. I tried with (\bselect\b|$) so I sure have a match, but it still crashes if it's at this size. Shorter, all good.

Comment: Thanks primo. You were on the right track.

Comment: @CornelRebegea if this regex is supposed to generate a match _if and only if_ there is a second select statement, then I believe it is written correctly. For clues about the Timeout issue, see [dan1111's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856025/php-ltrim-breaks-regular-expression/13856718#13856718), and consider marking it the solution if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Mario, I don't think such escaping is needed for PHP. Check out the examples in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: `\b` will result in a backspace inside the string (before it's even passed as a regular expression): http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php EDIT: Hm... I'm not sure this isn't a mistake. Maybe some special exception (would be odd behavior)?

Comment: @Mario, I admit I am not a PHP expert.  However, the documentation I linked to shows an example with `\b` interpreted as a word boundary within a double quoted string.  It could be a mistake in the documentation, I suppose. The escape sequences documentation seems pretty clear that it should need one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While testing this in a [PHP regex tester](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php) doesn't cause any problems, I think it may be a crash due to the way you formed your expression.  Consider this construct:

```
(.|\n)*?
```

The potential problem is the `|` operator, combined with `*`.  This could create a massive tree of possibilities when it doesn't match:

```
                    first character matches .
                               |
                          yes------no
                           |        |
         2nd character matches .    first character matches \n
                 |                                 |
            yes-----no                       yes--------no
             |       |                        |          |
      3rd char .    2nd char \n     2nd char matches .  2nd char matches .
```

The regex engine has to check 2^n  possibilities, where n is the number of characters remaining in the string.

The solution is to use the `/s` switch, as primo suggested in the comments.  Then you can simply use `.` to match anything including a newline.  Instead of 2^n possibilities, it will only have to check n possibilities.

Note: some regex engines are smart enough to avoid this pitfall.  In theory if the second "select" doesn't exist, the engine should be smart enough to know that it can never match and therefore give up.  When I test it in Perl for example, there is no problem.  And the above PHP regex tester doesn't have a problem.  But perhaps your version of PHP is older and not quite so optimised.

Comment: This did it. Thanks a big bunch! How can I accept your answer?

Comment: @CornelRebegea, You should see a checkbox that you can click in the upper left of the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because I only have 6 reputation points I don't see the checkbox. I'll get back to you.

Comment: My PHP version is 5.3.8, not that old. As I said before, PHPUnits doesn't have a problem with this. This is still a mistery for me. But your fix makes total sense.

Comment: @CornelRebegea, I think you also need to check whether `\b` needs to be escaped with an extra backslash.  Mario has convinced me this may be a problem.

Comment: tried that, I was desperate. no change though. with /s it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it would really crash, you would see at least some messages. I guess, you see no output at all. This is because your regular expression doesn't work.

You can fix it by either removing the final `\bselect\b` in your regular expression or append a `select` to your `$query`. Then it outputs some matches.

Comment: It's not that. I should get to the last print and see something. What I get is 'Connection interrupted' in the browser. The server stays up, but the execution is stopped.

Comment: @CornelRebegea have you tried running your script in the CLI, or checking apache error logs? Also, as @OlafDietsche said, your query only contains one `select`, so your regex can't possibly match anything.

Comment: @CornelRebegea I tested your example at the command line and there it outputs the match, when I modify either the regex or the search string. If it crashes, you should see something in your web server logs.